# How do I get my files back in Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, android-studio

I terminated my project to open another and now I've lost files/folders in the project I terminated in android studio but nowhere else. How do I get them back?

My files in Finder

[image: Finder]

My Files in VS Code

[image: VS Code]

My files in Android Studio

[image]

Comment: did you open the android folder or the project root folder with  android studio

Comment: I wasn't under the project root folder, silly mistake, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[make sure to select "Project" from this windows and not "Android"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3Wl5.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).